# Which part of UnLua for UE5 can be defined at runtime?

Tags: lua, unreal-5

I'm looking into options to allow a released UE5 game to be modded, with just "text files". That is, without having to use the Unreal Editor, and give access to the game code, to create the game "mod code".

Someone mentioned UnLua, but the (English) documentation is somewhat limited, and the comments in code are in Chinese (I can't read Chinese). So it's unclear to me, which part of the API, if at all, is available at "runtime".

My questions are:

1. Can you use Lua scripts that have been "user-defined", and were not part of the "released" game?
2. If #1 is "yes", what can you do in those scripts? More specifically, can you extend/customize classes, and override methods?